# Is this sentence grammatically correct? (From a novel)

Tags: grammar

I understand the meaning of the following sentence. However, I am not sure that I can write a sentence like it because I have never seen such a sentence structure before: "noun and a full sentence".

**A few minutes of determined sawing and the dog was free.** (This sentence is extracted from the book "The dog who came for Christmas" (Sue Pethick) p243.)

Comment: A moment's hesitation and all will be lost.https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nFGcCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT279&lpg=PT279&dq=a+moments+hesitation+and+all+will+be+lost&source=bl&ots=eOChyfy6mx&sig=s_MyqvPtCheH2OlFZZM4FuC0Djw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidx9jjq7zYAhXoC8AKHRD6DyEQ6AEIMzAB#v=onepage&q=a%20moments%20hesitation%20and%20all%20will%20be%20lost&f=false

Comment: Probably the best way to analyse this is that it's not a classically defined sentence but a sentence fragment. It certainly contains a complete thought / statement and is not confusing (though Tommy Cooper would no doubt have added 'It's lucky the dog had a saw.')  Modern thinking is that fragments used judiciously (as here) are fine except in very formal writing.

Comment: If you have not seen this before, then perhaps you can get more help in ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I can't see any difference between the example structure and, say, *One more year and I'll be retiring.* Would you say that's a "fragment"?

Comment: Avoid thanking people with an edit to your question. Instead, *upvote* answers you find helpful, *downvote* those you don't, and *accept* the answer that seems to work best for you.

Comment: @FF 'One more year' is a fragment. 'I've one more year to work, and [then] I'll be retiring.' 'And' is a coordinator, archetypically coordinating equivalent structures. Whether the term 'fragment' may be extended  to cover [frag + and + independent clause] would probably take days to research and profit little.

Comment: But it's not just any old fragment (see latest edit of my answer).

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the construction to:

[Noun phrase of quantity/duration] + and +  [Result: independent clause]

> Half an hour staring at this sentence and I'm no further than before.
>
> Two days of listening to her roommate practice the cello and Sarah was ready for a long vacation.
>
> A fresh cost of paint and your house is as good as sold.

The more prosaic way of expressing the same thing is with a subordinate clause beginning with *after*:

> After half an hour staring at this sentence, I'm no further than before.
>
> After two days of listening to her roommate practice the cello, Sarah was ready for a long vacation.
>
> After a fresh coat of paint your house is as good as sold.

Beginning with *after*, however, ruins the suspense — and perhaps humor — of the other construction.

Comment: Does this construction have a particular name?

Comment: @shoover: noun phrase of quantity/duration coordinated with independent clause, I suppose. I've been trying to come up with an example where there's no quantity, but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The word ‘novel’ is the clue.  Yes, it is perfectly acceptable *literary* English, even though it does not conform to the standard rules for sentence structure.  You can imagine an advertisement like this also, say for a cleaning product: ‘One wipe and the job is done!’.

Simple paraphrase will get us to a grammatical structure we recognise.  For example, we could turn the opening phrase into a temporal phrase:  “After a few minutes of determined sawing, the dog was free.”.  Now the predicate ‘was free, is modified by ‘after a few ... sawing.’.  But that could be syntactically ambiguous:  one possible way of parsing the sentence would have the dog doing the sawing.

Or she could have written:  “S/he sawed with determination for a few minutes, and then the dog was free.”.  But this too would be lame.

Sue Pethick is more skilful than that.  She wants all the reader’s attention to be on the dog being free.  She does not want so much as the delay of a temporal clause or even phrase.  She does not want any attention on the person doing the sawing:  It is very good story telling.

Comment: It may be an effective literary technique, but coordination rather than subordination is a hallmark of oral performance. "Three days of pullin' at that damned stump and it ain't budged a damn inch."

Comment: @KarlG I don’t follow.  Yes, your example has exactly the same in structure as the Sue Pethic passage.  It could have been an extract from a novel, or it could have been the expostulation of an exasperated farmer.  You can say that in that case, there is nothing particularly artful about Pethic’s sentence. But, as Horace said in his ‘Art of Poetry’, “Art consists in concealing the art.”

Comment: I mean that it's a particularly common pattern in spoken language and as likely to occur spontaneously in a rancher's encounter with a mesquite stump as in a novel.

Comment: @KarlG Indeed so.